# How to update a model? .updateAttributes is not a function

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm building a Node Express app, with Postgres as DB and Sequelize as ORM.

I have a `router.js` file:

```
router.route('/publish')
  .put((...args) => controller.publish(...args));
```

`controller.js` which looks like this:

```
publish(req, res, next) {
  helper.publish(req)
  .then((published) => {
    res.send({ success: true, published });
  });
}
```

And a `helper.js`

```
publish(req) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Article.findAll({
      where: { id: req.query.article_id },
      attributes: ['id', 'state']
    })
    .then((updateState) => {
      updateState.updateAttributes({
        state: 2
      });
    })
    .then((updateState) => {
      resolve(updateState);
    });
  });
}
```

So for example when I hit PUT `http://localhost:8080/api/publish?article_id=3555` I should get:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "published": [
    {
      "id": 3555,
      "state": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

The current state of the article is 1.

However, I get the following error `Unhandled rejection TypeError: updateState.updateAttributes is not a function`. When I remove the `updateState.updateAttributes` part from my helper.js I get the response with the current state.

How do I update the state of the article correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just change `findAll` with `findOne` , as you are just trying to find specific article by id :

```
Article.fineOne({  //<--------- Change here
    where: { id: req.query.article_id },
    attributes: ['id', 'state']
})
.then((updateState) => {
    updateState.updateAttributes({state: 2}); //<------- And this will work
})
```

---

But if you still want to go with findAll and to know how to use that , Please try this and read the comments , that will clear all your doubts :

```
Article.findAll({
    where: { id: req.query.article_id },
    attributes: ['id', 'state']
})
.then((updateState) => {
    // updateState will be the array of articles objects 
    updateState.forEach((article) => {
        article.updateAttributes({ state: 2 });
    });

    //-------------- OR -----------------
    updateState.forEach((article) => {
        article.update({ state: 2 });
    });
})
```